# How to get the same flyout of clipboard for phone and desktop in UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, clipboard

I saw that native app has the same flyout for desktop and phone. I'm wondering how can I get the same experience. Like the following
[image]

My app has different flyout shown for phone and for desktop. I don't know how can I can use the same flyout from native app, or at least make the flyout the same in phone and desktop.